# Spark Datasource Hudi table read using instant time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-hudi

I'm reading Hudi table using **Spark.read.format("hudi")**

want to understand how is this option works **hoodie.datasource.read.begin.instanttime**
Will it similar to hudi's hoodie_commit_ts column available in parquets files?

I'm **not** able to get same count between an external table on top of the same hudi path using hoodie_commit_ts column and below approach.

**Sample code is here**

beginTime = '20201201194517'

incremental_read_options = {'hoodie.datasource.query.type': 'incremental', 'hoodie.datasource.read.begin.instanttime': beginTime}

Incremental_DF = spark.read.format("org.apache.hudi").
options(**incremental_read_options).
load()

Answer (score 0):

Incremental queries and `hoodie.datasource.read.begin.instanttime` are based on `_hoodie_commit_time` data from the metadata table.

What you are accomplishing with this is an incremental read starting from the `beginTime` to the most recent data upsert. If you pass the exact time of a commit as `beginTime`, your query won't contain that commit. You would have to pass that (`beginTime - 1`) for that.

Also, you can use point in time queries, by passing the option `hoodie.datasource.read.end.instanttime` to restrain your query to a time point between `beginTime` and `endTime` (also exclusive).